# PDF Maps asking which program to use when opening

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, pdf

I save export out/ print to pdf maps that are later used online for viewing. The map should normally pop up after clicking from our website, but it asks for which program I would like to open. I want to print layout/ export to pdf in ArcGIS Pro and/or ArcMap and have my maps open on my website without asking which program needs to be selected for it to open.

Only a handful of pdf files are having this issues, later files I exported as pdf and handed off will not open when simply clicked upon. The majority of pdf maps on the website open without further requirements. Other people are having the same issue as me, this is not a local computer settings problem.

Comment: Sounds like a windows registry item. https://pdf.wondershare.com/pdf-knowledge/change-default-pdf-viewer-on-windows-10.html

Comment: I should have clarified and now it appears my post isn't sufficiently stating the issue, some of the pdfs on the website do open with no issues, later files that I have saved and handed off are having this issue. Other people are having the same issue.

Comment: Might be worth checking the Content-Disposition in the header of your web page. "Content-Disposition: inline" should show the pdf in the browser while "Content-Disposition: attachment" should cause it to download.